# Visual Studio Programming

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that I am completely not understanding.  We are focusing on for, while, and do while statements this chapter.  The question goes as follows...

"The payroll manager at Kenton Incorporated wants a program that allows him to enter an unknown number of payroll amounts for each of three stores: Store 1, Store 2, and Store 3.  The program should calculate the total payroll and then display te result on the screen."

I am completely lost on where to even start.  I guess what is confusing me is "an unknown number of payroll amounts".  I don't know how to make the user transistion to entering the next stores payroll amounts.  The question says nothings about using a sentinel value, but it also doesn't say not to use a sentinel value.

Any help or advice would be completely appreciated!!!!

Comment: Allow a special input to mean "next store".  A blank line, or `-1` as a payroll, for example.

Comment: you could ask the user to enter an amount, or just press enter (i.e. an empty input) to stop. that way you can keep collecting amounts until the user decides to stop.

Comment: I really want to believe this isn't a "do my homework" question.  So, what have you tried so far?  I fail to see what this has to do specifically with VS programming.  It's a question about how to write a solution to a simple program.

Comment: I like using EOF for unknown numbers of inputs. It's seamless to transfer the input to a file, it plays nice with some algorithms and reading loops, and it's just as easy to enter EOF as it is -1 or whatever.

Comment: EOF is fine if that's _ALL_ the input you want. If you want any other input (sat _two_ chunks of information, each variable in length, like an unknown-length group of temperatures for yesterday and another unknown-length group for today), you'll need to use a different sentinel. I believe that's not the case here but it's worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are three stores, you may want to keep the payroll amounts for each separate even though the specs don't seem to care. That way you can use a special store code of 0 to indicate you're done.

Pseudo-code follows:

```
store1 = 0
store2 = 0
store3 = 0
print "Enter store, or 0 to end: "
input storenum
while storenum <> 0:
    print "Enter a payroll amount: "
    input amount
    select storenum:
        case 1:
            store1 += amount
            end case
        case 2:
            store2 += amount
            end case
        case 3:
            store3 += amount
            end case
    end select
    print
    print "Enter store # or 0 to end"
    input storenum
end while
print
print "Store 1 payroll is ", store1
print "Store 2 payroll is ", store2
print "Store 3 payroll is ", store3
print
print "Total payroll is ", store1 + store2 + store3
```

That would lead to a transcript like:

```
Enter store, or 0 to end: 3
Enter a payroll amount: 33

Enter store, or 0 to end: 2
Enter a payroll amount: 22

Enter store, or 0 to end: 3
Enter a payroll amount: 11

Enter store, or 0 to end: 0

Store 1 payroll is 0
Store 2 payroll is 22
Store 3 payroll is 44

Total payroll is 66
```

Comment: I think my problem was that I was trying to combine all three stores under one do statement.  I didn't take into consideration that I could use three different statements, one for each store.  I used an outer do while statement, an inner do while statement, and an inner for statement.  Obviously, it didn't work and ended up reading like one huge mess.

Comment: Can I use case statements if I'm not using a switch statement?

Comment: @user2163574, no, not in C++. If there's some reason you cannot use `select/case` (like your educator does not allow it), you can achieve the same result with nested `if/else` constructs).